# Show multiple django forms from the one view and extending with inheritance

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

Say I have the following models:

```
class Revision:
    content = models.TextField()
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article', null=True)

class Article:
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    revision = models.OneToOneField('Revision', null=True)
```

I want to have *create* and *edit* pages for an Article. I've created `ModelForm`s for both. I've started to write a `CreateView` and `UpdateView` but not sure how to include both the forms in each view (which are then passed to the template and rendered as a `<form>`).

Most results I've found target creating two separate HTML `<form>`s with separate submit buttons, dynamically choosing different forms within the one view, or creating an array of forms with a fieldset. Instead, I want exactly two `ModelForm`s to be shown in the one `<form>` so that in my contrived example (yes, title should be on the revision but it isn't) I can change both the title and the content at once.

As far as I know I need to somehow manually add both forms to the context data, then when the user submits, bind each form (by passing the POST arguments to the constructor) and check their valid. I could fumble around doing this from scratch but would like to know the preferred way, perhaps with existing generic class based views. Which methods are best to overload to inject the desired functionality? Should generic views not be used for something this complicated (although it seems pretty simple to me)?

Let's say I then introduce a third model:

```
class Page:
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    article = models.OneToOneField('Article', null=True)
```

Now I'd like new views to create and edit a `Page`. Inheriting from the views for `Article`, I want to add a form to allow the slug to be modified. I'm bringing this up because I want a solution to the `Article` views above which is robust enough to handle aggregation without duplicating code. I imagine this situation is quite common and am hoping there is a simple solution I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your situation. This is a common pitfall. You can have as many forms and modelforms you like under a single `<form>`. If there is naming conflict issues, you can use `prefix`. You then deal with the posted data as such:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_revision = RevisionForm(request.POST)
    form_article = ArticleForm(request.POST, prefix='article')
    if form_revision.is_valid() and form_article.is_valid():
        article = form_article.save()
        revision = form_revision.save(commit=False)
        revision.article = article
        revision.save()
        # etc. etc. do whatever you like with your models
```

Edit: as requested in your comment, if it is a class-based view it is not very different:

```
class ContentNodeEditView(NodeView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        # ...
```

What I also do for various reasons, which I am sure you will appreciate later, is to add members as:

```
    form_revision_class = RevisionForm
```

And then use them as:

```
        form_revision = form_revision_class(request.POST)
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to say how to do this in the context of class based views? Should I be using generic views (I would have thought a situation as simple as mine would be supported) or build my own from scratch? Ideally I'd also like to add a new form via inheritance without rewriting the entire view.